# Equivalent replacement for LM7805CT

Tags: voltage-regulator

I have an [LM7805CT 5v voltage regulator](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/LM/LM7812.pdf) that is faulty.  I am unable to source a direct replacement locally but I do have a [TS2940](http://www.maplin.co.uk/media/pdfs/Module%2046321.pdf) in my parts bin that according to the datasheets should be an equivalent replacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recommended input and output capacitors on the 7805 are significantly smaller than the TS2940 so you'll need probably 10uF (as opposed to 0.1uF on 7805) for the output capacitor - this is implied in the table on page 2.

Input capacitance on 7805 can be as low as 0.33uF but the TS2940 needs at least 1uF - see notes on page 3.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, yes. The TS2940 is actually a better regulator, with a lower drop-out voltage. (0.6v at 1A, instead of the LM7805's 2v). Just make sure the TS2940 you have is the 5v version (part number TS2940xx-5.0, where xx is the package type).